# QML: binding loop when calculating Y position

Tags: qt, text, qml, qt5

Here my code:

```
FontLoader { id: font_bold; source: "qrc:/font/MyFont Bold.ttf" }
FontLoader { id: font_medium; source: "qrc:/font/MyFont Medium.ttf" }
FontMetrics { id: fontMetrics }

function getBaseline(fontFamily, fontPixelSize)
{
    fontMetrics.font.family = fontFamily;
    fontMetrics.font.pixelSize = fontPixelSize;
    return fontMetrics.ascent;
}

function getY(desiredY, fontFamily, fontPixelSize)
{
    return desiredY - getBaseline(fontFamily, fontPixelSize);
}

Text {
    x: 100
    y: getY(100, font.family, font.pixelSize)
    font.family: font_bold.name
    font.pixelSize: 96
    text: "foo"
}

Text {
    x: 200
    y: getY(150, font.family, font.pixelSize)
    font.family: font_medium.name
    font.pixelSize: 48
    text: "foo"
}
```

The goal is to calculate the actual `y` position from the desired one, removing the ascent offset of the current font, so the baseline will sit on the desired position.

I got this error for both lines `y: getY(...)`:

> QML QQuickText: Binding loop detected for property "y"

I don't see where is the binding loop. The `y` property is calculated as desired position - font ascent. Both are not related to `y` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using the `FontMetrics` for both font's, changing the ascent continuously. Remember that you are binding a function to the y-position and thus every time the `FontMetrics` is set to another font it will trigger an update on the y-position of both `Text`'s.

So, I propose to use two `FontMetrics`, one for the bold and one for the medium.

```
FontMetrics { id: fontMetricsBold; font: font_bold }
FontMetrics { id: fontMetricsMedium; font: font_medium }

Text {
    x: 100
    y: 100 - fontMetricsBold.ascent
    font.family: font_bold.name
    font.pixelSize: 96
    text: "foo"
}

Text {
    x: 200
    y: 150 - fontMetricsMedium.ascent
    font.family: font_medium.name
    font.pixelSize: 48
    text: "bar"
}
```

Note, I don't have the fonts so I leave that as an exercise. Maybe configuring the `FontMetrics` has to be done differently with respect to the `FontLoader`.

Comment: Well, I would like to use only one `FontMetrics` for example in a function, because I have a lot of different combinations of font family and sizes. This one is just a minimal example, but I cannot use one font metrics for each different settings. Furthermore some of these are dynamic, as the size changes at run-time.

Comment: I could feel that coming ;-) However, you can put the `FontMetrics` inside each `Text` and bind the of that metric to the font of the parent `Text`

Comment: Got it. It's a different approach about code re-usability... I'm not used yet and I always try to write only one function...